# Objective-C : Cant connect to server using Socket.IO

Tags: ios, objective-c, socket.io

I'm using Socket.IO-Client-Swift' -13.2.0' to implement my project in Objective-C. I'm trying to connect to a Node.js service using Socket.IO and have followed the documentation for Objective-C. But when i try to run my code, the console logs 'tried connecting socket when engine isn't open' and cant get through.

Following is my code,

```
@import SocketIO;
NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://URL_STRING:PORT_NUMBER"];

SocketManager *manager = [[SocketManager alloc] initWithSocketURL:url config:@{@"log":@yES, @"compress":@yES}];
SocketIOClient *socket = [manager defaultSocket];

[socket on:@"connect" callback:^(NSArray* data, SocketAckEmitter* ack) {
NSLog(@"socket connected");
}];

[socket connect];
```

And the console,

```
2018-06-01 00:22:06.694853+1000 [885:732318] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Adding handler for event: connect
2018-06-01 00:22:06.695467+1000 [885:732318] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: statusChange with data: [connecting]
2018-06-01 00:22:06.695578+1000 [885:732318] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Joining namespace /
2018-06-01 00:22:06.695639+1000 [885:732318] LOG SocketManager: Tried connecting socket when engine isn't open. Connecting
2018-06-01 00:22:06.695679+1000 [885:732318] LOG SocketManager: Adding engine
2018-06-01 00:22:06.697262+1000 [885:732355] LOG SocketEngine: Starting engine. Server: http://URL_STRING:PORT_NUMBER
2018-06-01 00:22:06.697323+1000 [885:732355] LOG SocketEngine: Handshaking
2018-06-01 00:22:06.699886+1000 [885:732355] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Doing polling GET http://URL_STRING:PORT_NUMBER/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1
```

How to solve this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: Have used CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost or reading this https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/UsingSocketsandSocketStreams.html to understand better this topic, cheers.

Comment: Make sure your client version of the socket is compatible with the servrr version . This should primary be done while implementing it

Answer (score 1):

Resolved:

Set manager to strong.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) SocketManager* manager;
```

Comment: do we need to make same for SocketIOClient ??

Comment: @NIRAVBHAVSAR  Yes, For handling error and check socket status in singleton class.

Comment: Thank you Buddy! .. can u pls share ur socket connection code OBJ C? as i can not able to connect server , i tried each and every possible way ... is there anything different thing for xcode 12?

Answer (score 0):

```
SocketIOClient *socket = [manager socketForNamespace:@"/"];
```

add this line and it will

instead of

```
SocketIOClient *socket = [manager defaultSocket];
```